# Mean value of multiple columns

Tags: matlab, for-loop, mean

I have searched a lot to find the solution, but nothing really works for me I think.

I have `n` data files containing two columns each (imported using `uigetfile`). To extract the data, I use a `for loop` like this:

```
for i=1:n
    data{i}=load(filename{i});
    x{i}=data{i}(:,1);
    y{i}=data{i}(:,2);  
end
```

Now, I want to get the mean value for each row of all the (let's say) x-values. E.g.:

```
x{1} = [1,4,7,8]

x{2} = [1,2,6,9]
```

Then I want something like

```
x_mean = [1,3,6.5,8.5]
```

I have tried (where `k` is number of rows)

```
for i=1:n
        data{i}=load(filename{i});
        x{i}=data{i}(:,1);
        y{i}=data{i}(:,2);  
    j=1:k
        x_mean=sum(x{i}(j))/n
end
```

But I can't use multiple counters in a for loop (as I understand). Moreover, I don't use `mean` as I don't see how I can use it in this case.

If someone could help me, it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the contents of each numeric array in the cell `x` into a new numeric array `x_num` like so:

```
x_num = [x{:}]
```

Computing the mean is then as simple as

```
mean_x = mean( [x{:}] )
```

For your example, that gives you the mean of *all* numbers in *all* arrays in `x`, which will therefore be a scalar.

If you want to compute the mean of all the rows (column-wise mean), as your example would indicate), you have to concatenate your arrays vertically, which you can do with `cat`:

```
mean_x_columnwise = mean( cat(1,x{:}) )
```

If you want to take the mean over all the columns (row-wise mean), you should only have to tell `mean` that you are looking at a different dimension:

```
mean_x_rowwise = mean( cat(1,x{:}), 2)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is the solution. What I want is a single column with 100 scalars (number of rows), being the mean of each row for all the n columns. E.g. if I have two columns, x{1} and x{2}, and the first row reads 3 and 7 respectively, then the first value in mean_x should be (3+7)/2=5. Does this make sense, or did I just not understand your solution? :)

Comment: @NielsMøller: did you *try* my solution? :) Btw, your example would suggest you wanted to have a single *row* containing the means of all the *rows*. If you want the means over all the *columns*...See my latest edits.

Comment: I did try your solution :) The last edit is what I meant - row-wise mean. But it seems like I only get the mean of the last column (i.e. identical to its value). Is this because of my for-loop, and the counter i? In other words, I do get a single column, but its values are identical to the last column I imported (i.e. x{n}).

Comment: @NielsMøller: Ah. I take it you are placing this line of code inside your loop? It's vectorized, so you should place it right after the loop, and let the loop *only* collect data into all the `x{i}`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Not sure if it worked. According to the workspace, mean_x_rowwise is <300x1 double>. I would have thought it should be 100x1 ?

Comment: @NielsMøller: well, My solution withstands basic tests...I don't have access to your actual data; it could be that one of your `n` datafiles is different from the rest? Perhaps try it on the first 3 data files or so.

Comment: Yeah, I think you have helped me a lot - I'll see what I can do, but you have given me some good ideas. Thanks!